# "Ghost" Bottom Navigation Bar when fragment loads in home activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm currently working on the home screen of my app and am using fragments to load the different "pages" when a user clicks on a button on a bottom navigation bar.  What I've found is that when I load the home screen the bottom bar seems to reload itself again, creating two bars, one in the middle of the page and one in the proper position at the bottom of the screen (while the middle bar isn't actually functional).  I'm thinking that the fragment loading in the activity is the cause, but I'm not entirely sure on how to solve it.  Below is an image of the problem as well as some of the code that I've got.

[image: image of android app screen highlighting the "ghost" navigation bar]
activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="225dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

home_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            design:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            design:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            design:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            design:srcCompat="@drawable/main_screen_placeholder" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/airplane_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            design:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            design:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            design:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            design:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder"
            design:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_airplane_48" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="225dp" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="349dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            design:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            design:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            design:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tokyo_placeholder">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/destination_headline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Featured Destinations"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">


                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/featured_destinations_gallery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/saved_trips_headline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Saved Trips"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
            elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- TODO: Make page scrollable and fix bottom navigation bar -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

HomeActivity.kt

```
package projectrc_android.project_rc

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import projectrc_android.project_rc.R.*


class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var current_fragment = id.home_fragment
    private val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layout.activity_home)

        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        val bottomNavigationBar = findViewById(id.bottom_nav) as BottomNavigationView // get bottom navigation bar
        bottomNavigationBar.selectedItemId = R.id.home_button  // set the selected menu item to home at the start
        ShowFragment(R.id.home_button) // load the home fragment item into the activity
        var selectedMenuItem = bottomNavigationBar.selectedItemId  // get currently selected menu item

        bottomNavigationBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            if(item.itemId != selectedMenuItem) { // if the user picks a button that's NOT the currently selected one
                selectedMenuItem = item.itemId // update the selected menu item
                ShowFragment(item.itemId)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun ShowFragment(menuButton: Int) {
        val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        when (menuButton) {
            R.id.home_button -> {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment())
                current_fragment = R.id.home_fragment
            }
            R.id.inbox_button -> {
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, InboxFragment())
                    current_fragment = R.id.inbox_fragment
            }
            R.id.account_button -> {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, AccountFragment())
                current_fragment = R.id.account_fragment
            }
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
package projectrc_android.project_rc

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val imagePaths = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cuba_placeholder, R.drawable.s_korea_placeholder,
            R.drawable.greece_placeholder, R.drawable.san_francisco_placeholder, R.drawable.cuba_placeholder, R.drawable.s_korea_placeholder,
            R.drawable.greece_placeholder, R.drawable.san_francisco_placeholder)
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)
        val destinationGallery = view.findViewById(R.id.featured_destinations_gallery) as LinearLayout
        //set up toolbar in place of action bar (and remove title)


        //dynamically add images to scrollview
        addImageToLayout(view.context, destinationGallery, imagePaths, 260, 360)
        return view
    }


    private fun addImageToLayout(context : Context, layout: LinearLayout, imagePaths: IntArray, width: Int, height: Int) {
        val numberOfImages = imagePaths.size
        for (index in 0 until numberOfImages) {
            val imageView = ImageView(context)
            imageView.id = index
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2)
            Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(imagePaths[index])
                    .apply(RequestOptions()
                            .override(width, height)
                            .centerCrop())
                    .into(imageView)
            layout.addView(imageView)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're adding the fragment even if it's already added (see after rotation for example)

Comment: Even when the page loads for the first time? (it happens even when I haven't actually touched the bottom nav bar, like right when the home screen opens up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` in both `activity_home.xml` as well as in `home_fragment.xml`. So you are seeing two bottom navigation views.

you have set listener to the activity's navigation view But didn't set any listener to the fragment's navigation view and so the one that is shown in the middle is not functional.

Remove navigation view from `home_fragment.xml`. It should solve the issue.